# docker run claims a command needs admin access

Tags: docker

```
bash-3.2$ docker run -it -e DISPLAY=$IP:0 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v `pwd`:`pwd` josh:latest
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

bash: /home/ros/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

And my dockerfile is:

```
FROM ros:kinetic-robot-xenial

MAINTAINER Joshua Schraven

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --assume-yes \
vim-nox \
sudo \
python-pip \
ros-kinetic-desktop-full \
ros-kinetic-turtlebot3 \
ros-kinetic-turtlebot3-bringup \
ros-kinetic-turtlebot3-description \
ros-kinetic-turtlebot3-fake \
ros-kinetic-turtlebot3-gazebo \
ros-kinetic-turtlebot3-msgs \
ros-kinetic-turtlebot3-navigation \
ros-kinetic-turtlebot3-simulations \
ros-kinetic-turtlebot3-slam \
ros-kinetic-turtlebot3-teleop

# create non-root user
ENV USERNAME ros
RUN adduser --ingroup sudo --disabled-password --gecos "" --shell /bin/bash --home /home/$USERNAME $USERNAME
RUN bash -c "echo ros:ros | chpasswd"
ENV HOME /home/$USERNAME
USER $USERNAME

# create catkin_ws
RUN mkdir /home/$USERNAME/catkin_ws
WORKDIR /home/$USERNAME/catkin_ws

# add catkin env
RUN echo 'source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash' >> /home/$USERNAME/.bashrc
RUN echo 'source /home/$USERNAME/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash' >> /home/$USERNAME/.bashrc
```

I don't know what command is causing the problem, nor how I would trouble shoot that myself.

Comment: which line are you referring to? I don't see a sudo on a RUN...

Comment: that's just installing the sudo tool, isn't it?

Comment: No and in fact, the assumption of this docker file is that it needs to run as root.  Yes, it does install sudo at the start along with all the other listed packages.

Comment: Indeed -- hazard of not reading closely enough. While a phone screen isn't a very plausible way to explain misreading `\ ` for `&&\ `, I'm going to try to do so regardless. :)

Comment: ...that said, I'm not sure the two errors have much anything to do with each other. How is the file `/home/$USERNAME/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` supposed to get created so it can be `source`ed, when you're only creating its parent directory two lines above, and not unpacking anything into it in the interim?

Comment: Right thanks for helping me see that. Can you tell what line or why that particular error is coming up?